# How to abort a active download of a package in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, packages

I was downloading a package from a terminal. Actually i want to install some package 'A'. But,by mistake installing some other package 'B'. So, i wanted to stop the download of that package 'B' and start downloading 'A'. But, i couldnt able to do that. I reset my network connnection. I could stop downloading the package B. But, the administratory directory was locked and wasn't able to download other packages which made me to restart my system.

Is there a way or any command to abort the active download of packages in ubuntu. ?

-Thanks

Vinaychalluru.

Comment: isn't there an askubuntu exchange better suited to this?

Comment: @raticulin, yep: [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to gracefully abort download by pressing `CTRL+C` in the `apt-get install <package>` terminal window.